# VBA - How to download webpage after following the hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently running the following code which opens up all the links I have in a column. However, after opening the links, because it is opening up so many tabs (as expected and intended), I would like it to then download the contents of the web pages to a pdf and store them in a folder on my machine.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set Sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Sh
        Set Rng = .Range("L3:L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)        
    End With

    For Each Cell In Rng
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Text
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do some research yourself. SO is not a code writing service. If you show us the code you tried and where that failed we are willing to help you out or point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Luuklag, have been doing research and attempting to run the code myself with many failed attempts. I stripped it back to the above as I believed I was taking the wrong approach.

Comment: This should get you started (if this question is not a dupe of this one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900668/saving-webpage-as-pdf-to-certain-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving webpage as PDF to certain directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900668/saving-webpage-as-pdf-to-certain-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this will import everything from a web page and place it in Cell A1.  You can easily dump the contents of the cell to a PDF (save as PDF), if that is your intention.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com" ' should work for any URL
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

            Range("A1").Value = .document.body.innertext

            .Quit
        End With

End Sub
```