# Print Web Page as pdf based on cell values

Tags: html, vba

I have a code that will loop through the urls which are in column B and print as Pdf. This macro works fine till here. My question is, i want to save pdf based on cell values in column A in the respective path of column C.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
Dim Explorer As Object
Dim eQuery As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim fTime As Single
    Lr1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For L = 2 To Lr1
        Set Explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        URL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & L)
        Explorer.Navigate URL
TryAgain:
            fTime = Timer
                Do While fTime > Timer - 5
                DoEvents
            Loop
        eQuery = Explorer.QueryStatusWB(6)
        If eQuery And 2 Then
            Explorer.ExecWB 6, 2, "", ""
                fTime = Timer
                    Do While fTime > Timer - 2
                    DoEvents
                Loop
            Else
GoTo TryAgain
        End If
    Next L
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but move your `Set Explorer = ...` statement to run **before** your `For` loop. You only need to create the Internet Explorer object once, then reuse it for each URL.  The way you're running now, you are creating separate IEs for every URL. Where is your code that saves the web page as a PDF?

Comment: Thanks for your response peterT, the line Explorer.ExecWB 6, 2 is the line which saves web page as pdf. This gives popup window which is nothing but print save As window..

Comment: I think [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903866/4717755) gives you a complete solution.

Comment: I think this takes much time to understand the code. Thank you so much for helping me in this..